# Export Access database with multiple tables to Excel with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The title says it about all. I'm trying to write a VBA script that would allow me to run inside Access and it would export all database tables as separate sheets into and Excel file with the same name as the database:

```
Sub exportTablesToXLS()
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef, db As DAO.Database
    Dim out_file As String

    out_file = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & db.DatabaseName & ".xls"

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    For Each td In db.TableDefs
        If Left(td.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
            'We do not need MSys tables in excel file
        Else
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            td.Name, out_file, True, Replace(td.Name, "dbo_", "") 'We do not need dbo prefix in sheetnames
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Problems I'm having I would like your help on:

- see line `out_file` -> db.DatabaseName return an error. How can I correctly get the database name of the current Access database?
- I want to output a logfile (simple textfile) as well. How can I read, for each database table, the number of rows that have been exported and report eventual errors that occured?

Any help to improve this script is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your **db** variable doesn't refer to the current database (yet - it is set in the following line), and the property is `Name` (I haven't encountered `DatabaseName`):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim sLast As String

    MsgBox db.Name
    'F:\Documents and Settings\student\My Documents\Staff Database.accdb
    sLast = InStrRev(db.Name, "\")
    MsgBox Right(db.Name, Len(db.Name) - sLast)
    'Staff Database.accdb
End Sub
```

Name gives the full path and filename, the second MsgBox reduces this to just the filename.
(There may be another way to get the filename without having to parse `Name`..)

To get the number of rows exported you could open a `Recordset` for the table(s), reading the `RecordCount` property. A text file could be created using the **FileSystemObject** object. Sample code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPath)
oFile.WriteLine "test" 
oFile.Close
```

Or even just simple file (VBA) I/O:

```
Open pathname For mode [Access access] [lock] As [#]filenumber [Len=reclength]
```

(the `FileSystemObject` is easier to work with)

To report errors you'll need to create your own error-handling routines, and an error-logging procedure. This has been done before and a little searching will uncover some code. Essentially, each (important) event has error-handling code that calls a logging procedure. This procedure creates a record in a table to store all relevant information: date, time, which form was open, etc., etc.

A quick Google uncovered [this page](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/how-to-log-errors-in-microsoft-access/750) about logging Access errors.